# React native, delay api call?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a method called: `onChangeText`

It means every time I type, it will search the remote api.
**How do I delay the remote api call?** i.e. let user types certain things, then connect the api, rather than connect every key stroke.

```
onChangeText(title) {
        console.log('-- chg text --');
        console.log(title);

        this.props.searchApi(title);
    }
```

The component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SearchBar, Divider } from 'react-native-elements';
import { View, ScrollView, Text, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


// action creator
import { searchApi } from './reducer';


class SearchContainer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    onChangeText(title) {
        console.log('-- chg text --');
        console.log(title);

        this.props.searchApi(title);
    }

    onClearText(e) {

        console.log('-- clear text --');
        console.log(e);
    }

    render() {
        const {  } = this.props;

        const containerStyle = {
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
        }

        const searchStyle = {
            width: 300,
            height: 45
        };


        return (
            <View
                style={containerStyle}
            >
                <Image
                    source={require('../../asset/img/logo.png')}
                    style={{
                        height: 150,
                        width: 150
                    }}
                />

                <SearchBar
                    cancelButtonTitle="Cancel"
                    placeholder='Search'
                    containerStyle={searchStyle}
                    onChangeText={this.onChangeText.bind(this)}
                    onClearText={this.onClearText.bind(this)}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {

    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        searchApi: () => dispatch(searchApi())
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchContainer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lodash debounce. It is used for this exact use case

Sample React example. Should be able to port to native the same way

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { debounce } from 'lodash'

class TableSearch extends Component {

  //********************************************/

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        value: props.value
    }

    this.changeSearch = debounce(this.props.changeSearch, 250)
  }

  //********************************************/

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const val = e.target.value

    this.setState({ value: val }, () => {
      this.changeSearch(val)
    })
  }

  //********************************************/

  render() {

    return (
        <input
            onChange = {this.handleChange}
            value = {this.props.value}
        />
    )
  }

  //********************************************/

}
```